# How to refresh the UI of a fragment using LiveData after Firestore data loads

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm making an Android app using Kotlin with Firebase products. I have successful connections with Firestore and can successfully retrieve the data I want, but I am having difficulty displaying it within a RecyclerView.

When the application loads, and after a user has logged in, my Firestore queries use the UID of the user to get a list of their assignments. Using logs I can see that this occurs without issue as the home screen loads. Within the home screen fragment I have data binding for the RecyclerView and setup my ViewModel to have the fragment observe the returned Firestore data.

I believe it is a misunderstanding on my part on exactly how LiveData works because if I tap the bottom nav icon for the home screen to trigger a refresh of the UI then the list populates and I can use the app as desired. Therefore my observer/LiveData must not be setup properly as it is not automatically refreshing once the data has changed (null list to not null list).

As I'm new to programming I'm sure I've fallen into a number of pitfalls and done a few things incorrectly, but I've been searching through StackOverflow and YouTube for help on this issue for months now. Unfortunately I don't have all of the links saved to every video and every post.

I've tried tweaking the ViewModel and the Repository/Database class (singleton) to different effects and currently I'm at my best version with only a single tap required to refresh the UI. Previously it took multiple taps.

from the Database class

```
private val assignments = MutableLiveData<List<AssignmentModel>>()

private fun getUserAssignments(c: ClassModel) {
        val assignmentQuery = assignmentRef.whereEqualTo("Class_ID", c.Class_ID)

        assignmentQuery.addSnapshotListener { documents, _ ->
            documents?.forEach { document ->
                val a = document.toObject(AssignmentModel::class.java)
                a.Assignment_ID = document.id
                a.Class_Title = c.Title

                a.Formatted_Date_Due = formatAssignmentDueDate(a)

                assignmentMap[a.Assignment_ID] = a
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAssignments() : LiveData<List<AssignmentModel>> {
        assignments.value = assignmentMap.values.toList().filter {
            if (it.Date_Due != null) it.Date_Due!!.toDate() >= Calendar.getInstance().time else true }
            .sortedBy { it.Date_Due }
        return assignments
    }
```

from the ViewModel

```
class AssignmentListViewModel internal constructor(private val myDatabase: Database) : ViewModel() {

    private var _assignments: LiveData<List<AssignmentModel>>? = null

    fun getAssignments() : LiveData<List<AssignmentModel>> {
        var liveData = _assignments
        if (liveData == null) {
            liveData = myDatabase.getAssignments()
            _assignments = liveData
        }
        return liveData
    }
}
```

from the Fragment

```
class AssignmentList : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var model: AssignmentListViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = AssignmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val factory = InjectorUtils.provideAssignmentListViewModelFactory()
        model = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(AssignmentListViewModel::class.java)

        val assignmentAdapter = AssignmentAdapter()
        binding.assignmentRecycler.adapter = assignmentAdapter
        updateUI(assignmentAdapter)
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun updateUI(adapter: AssignmentAdapter) {
        model.getAssignments().observe(this, Observer { assignments ->
            if (assignments.isNotEmpty()) adapter.submitList(assignments)
        })
    }
}
```

Again, I expect the RecyclerView to populate automatically once the data from Firestore appears, but it doesn't. The screen remains empty until I tap the home screen button.

These snippets show the most recent changes I've made. Originally I had the Firestore query function returning the LiveData directly. I also had a much simpler ViewModel of something like fun getAssignments() = myDatabase.getAssignments().

Thanks for any and all help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When troubleshooting this issue, I'd recommend starting by looking at two things.

#### Take a look at where/when you're updating your LiveData

The goal is whenever the data in Firebase updates, your `assignments` LiveData updates your UI. Something like:

1. Firestore updates
2. Firestore triggers SnapshotListener
3. SnapshotListener updates LiveData
4. LiveData observer updates UI

So in your snapshot listener, you should be updating your LiveData, which is what I think you're missing. So it would be something like:

```
// Where you define your SnapshotListner
assignmentQuery.addSnapshotListener { documents, _ ->
    // Process the data
    documents?.forEach { document ->
        val a = document.toObject(AssignmentModel::class.java)
        a.Assignment_ID = document.id
        a.Class_Title = c.Title

        a.Formatted_Date_Due = formatAssignmentDueDate(a)

        assignmentMap[a.Assignment_ID] = a
    }

    // Update your LiveData
    assignments.value = assignmentMap.values.toList().filter {
    if (it.Date_Due != null) it.Date_Due!!.toDate() >= Calendar.getInstance().time else true }
    .sortedBy { it.Date_Due }

}
```

Now every time your Firestore updates, your LiveData will update and your UI should update.

Given the code change, `getAssignments()` can just return assignments. You can do this using a Kotlin [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties), covered [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data/#5):

```
private val _assignments = MutableLiveData<List<AssignmentModel>>()
val assignments: LiveData<List<AssignmentModel>>
    get() = _assignments
```

**As for why it's not working at the moment**, right now you call `getAssignments()` once on start up. This will filter an empty `assignmentMap.values` (I believe - might be worth checking), because when it's called, Firebase hasn't finished getting you any data. And when Firebase does get it's new data, it triggers the listener, but you don't update the LiveData.

#### Mind where you're setting up your listeners/observers

A tricky thing with LiveData observers and Firebase listeners is to make sure you only set them up once.

For your Firebase listener, you should be setting up the listener when you initialize your database and not every single time you call `getUserAssignments`. Then you wouldn't need all the null checking in the ViewModel, which essentially ensures that at least the ViewModel won't call getUserAssignments twice....but if you have other classes interacting with your database, they might call `getUserAssignments` multiple times and then you have tons of extra listeners.

Also, make sure you [detach your listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

One way to handle this is described in Doug Stevenson's talk [Firebase and Android Jetpack: Fit Like a Glove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfdgH2371oE) - the talk includes a demo code [here](https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack). The part that's related to this is how he handles [LiveData](https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/hyperaware/android/firebasejetpack/livedata/firestore/FirestoreDocumentLiveData.kt) -- notice how the class includes adding and removing the listener. The TL;DR is that he's using [LiveData's lifecycle awareness](https://youtu.be/OMcDk2_4LSk?t=141) to automatically do Firebase listener setup and cleanup. How that's done is a bit complicated, so I'd suggest watching the talk [from here](https://youtu.be/bfdgH2371oE?t=380).

For your LiveData, setup/tear down looks correct since it's getting setup in onCreateView (and torn down automatically via the fact it's lifecycle aware). I might rename `updateUI` to something like `setupUIObservation`, since `updateUI` sounds like something you call multiple times. As with the Firebase listeners, you want to make sure you're not setting up the same LiveData observer more than once.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, Lyla! You were correct in that it was all a matter of where I was trying to update my LiveData. I had tried having the LiveData assignment within the function to get the data from Firestore, but I hadn't tried within the snapshot listener itself.

Now the UI refreshes automatically as the data loads and it even refreshes with the updates from Firestore on the specific documents. :)

I know I probably have some issues with my Firebase listeners as well. I'll take a look at Doug's talk. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think setting lifecycle of the fragment "this" as the first parameter to observe method is not right ,because fragment's view is recreated everytime you press app's task or home button which mean your observer won't tear down as fragment's view does that's because your observer is tied to the whole fragment life cycle not the view life cycle .This implies that in the next time you reopen the app onCreateView method would create new observer listening to fragment life cycle but won't tear down unless fragment itself is destroyed ,this approach would end you up having multiple observers

Comment: What it is suggested is that you use getViewLifecycleOwner() instead of using fragment life cycle  "this"

Comment: if you want to user fragment life cycle you'd better calling from fragment's onCreate() instead

Comment: @Lyla can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007155/how-to-query-firestore-in-mvvm-android-architecture